# What are fast algorithms/data structures for querying near points on the surface of a sphere?

Tags: algorithm, haskell, data-structures, functional-programming

I want data structure with the following methods:

```
insert :: Point3D -> a -> SphereMap a -> SphereMap a
remove :: Point3D -> a -> SphereMap a -> SphereMap a
query :: Float -> Point3D -> SphereMap a -> [a]
```

Where `insert` and `remove` add 3D-indexed values to the data structure, `query` receives an angle and a point, and returns a list of all values that are within that angular distance of the point with respect to origin (0,0,0).

What kinds of data-structures exist for such requirements?

Comment: So the origin is always the same?

Comment: The [`ShadeTree`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/manifolds-0.2.2.0/docs/Data-Manifold-TreeCover.html#g:6) structure from my `manifolds` package is intended for precisely this sort of task. You would _not_ work with 3D-points then though, but with actual points of the [sphere surface type](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/manifolds-0.2.2.0/docs/Data-Manifold-Types.html#t:S-178-). Which I frankly haven't tested yet with `ShadeTree`, but it should work just as well on the sphere as it does on real vector spaces.

Comment: Actually, `SphereMap` would rather be represented by [`PointsWeb`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/manifolds-0.2.2.0/docs/Data-Manifold-Web.html), which uses `ShadeTree` as its underlying spatial lookup structure but has extra topological info which you could use to perform the within-distance lookup. — **Neither** of these types support `insert` and `remove`, though – it's only build-once and keep as it is; the only way to change points is to dissolve the structure and build it from scratch (because the tree nodes are based on centroids, so the entire structure changes if you move a leaf).

Answer (score 2):

The usual approach is to use either quad-trees for 2d data or octrees for 3d data. A quad-tree splits the area of concern into 4 quadrants based on X and Y thresholds. For each quadrant, if it contains zero or 1 points then end, otherwise subdivide the quadrant into sub-quadrants and repeat. This gives you a tree of points in which the tree geometry reflects neigbouring geometry. You can then write an algorithm to traverse the tree finding all the quadrants that intersect the radius of your search.
Oct-trees are the same in 3 dimensions,splitting by X, Y and Z.
See http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-use-quadtrees-to-detect-likely-collisions-in-2d-space--gamedev-374 for details.

Comment: I understand how quad-trees work, the issue is how do I translate 3D points on the surface of a sphere to meaningful 2D points on the quad-tree range.

Comment: @Viclib for an Octree approach, you'd just embed the sphere as a unit sphere in ℝ³ and perform the lookups there (just normalise the vector of any point you want to insert). This would probably work just fine, though it's arguably less elegant than working in the actual _S²_ manifold. If you use that, I wouldn't rely on a quad / _k_-d tree though – you could theoretically span a quadtree in the polar coordinate representation, but it would get you in trouble because the ℝ²-metric in that system doesn't agree with the natural one on the sphere surface.

Comment: Putting it more simply, you can ignore the fact that your nearest neighbours should be on the surface on a sphere. Whichever points are the nearest neighbours in normal 3D space are automatically also the closest point on the surface on the sphere. So you can simply use a octree, kd-tree or R-Tree (R*Tree, ...). For a lot of data (10e5 points or more) or with frequent updates, I would suggest the PH-Tree (a 'trie'  variant of the quadtree).